# Python regex.findall not finding all matches of shorter length

Tags: python, regex, findall

How can I find all matches that don't necessarily consume all characters with `*` and `+` modifiers?

```py
import regex as re
matches = re.findall("^\d+", "123")
print(matches)
# actual output: ['123']
# desired output: ['1', '12', '123']
```

I need the matches to be anchored to the start of the string (hence the `^`), but the `+` doesn't even seem to be considering shorter-length matches. I tried adding `overlapped=True` to the `findall` call, but that does not change the output.

Making the regex non-greedy (`^\d+?`) makes the output `['1']`, `overlapped=True` or not. Why does it not want to keep searching further?

I could always make shorter substrings myself and check those with the regex, but that seems rather inefficient, and surely there must be a way for the regex to do this by itself.

```py
s = "123"
matches = []
for length in range(len(s)+1):
    matches.extend(re.findall("^\d+", s[:length]))
print(matches)
# output: ['1', '12', '123']
# but clunky :(
```

**Edit: the `^\d+` regex is just an example, but I need it to work for any possible regex. I should have stated this up front, my apologies.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `overlapped=True` with the PyPi regex module and [reverse searching](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#reverse-searching) `(?r)`

Then reverse the resulting list from [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import regex as re

res = re.findall(r"(?r)^\d+", "123", overlapped=True)
res.reverse()
print(res)
```

Output

```
['1', '12', '123']
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##FYxBCgIxDEX3PUXoqkUZ0FF3g5dwKUKh0SnUNiRR9PQ1wl883oNPX117m8coT@qswPjADyQxcI5RYDGa7qXlVGtgH84cb9e88Vvwu/0MuhYBWwJFUTgcT1b6G7kmIszLhV8Y/0cTo1nBEB1xaRrMxTF@).

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I need, but it does not work for all regexes. E.g.,  `(?r)^\d+\w\d+` will result in `['123d456', '123d45', '123d4', '123']`, even though `'123'` should not match `\d+\w\d+` (where is the letter and number at the end?)

Comment: @ArtieVandelay Using `\w` also matches `\d`

Comment: Oh wait yeah, you're right! Don't know how I missed that. :p This indeed seems to be what I need then!

Comment: You could also write it with the reverse as a single line `res = re.findall(r"(?r)^\d+", "123", overlapped=True)[::-1]`

Comment: I am not too concerned with the order of the output as long as all substrings are present :)

Answer (score 5):

How about a positive lookbehind assertion:

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=(^\d+))', '123')
['1', '12', '123']
```

Comment: This might be it! It's kind of hard to wrap my head around lookbehinds and lookaheads, but do you know if there are any pitfalls to this or things I should be aware of?

Comment: @ArtieVandelay, this is not very efficient: solution by Andrej will be faster for longer input strings. And not every regex engine supports lookbehinds of variable length (standard `re` doesn't, for example). Also it will work only for simple patterns: for example you can't do it for something like `\d+\s\w+` as straightforward as here. Otherwise it's valid regex-only approach, if you need one for some reason.

Comment: @markalex Indeed, I am finding it to not work on certain complex patterns. My actual use case isn't solely for `^\d+` because I do not know what regexes I will get in advance. Andrej's solution only works on simple examples where substrings of a longer match are automatically also a match, which you cannot guarantee with all possible regexes. Currently I am using the naive substring approach, constantly rematching each substring to the regex.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use standard library `re`:

```py
import re

matches = re.findall("^\d+", "123")
out = [m[:i] for m in matches for i in range(1, len(m)+1)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['1', '12', '123']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

m = re.findall(r'\d', '123')
op = ["".join(m[:i]) for i in range(1, len(m) + 1)]
print(op)
```

This is a bit better as re.findall() is called only once

Comment: [Clearly it is possible using only regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741244/21363224). Consider modifying your answer regarding that part.

Comment: Also, your approach will produce undesired output for input like `123 345`.